# Having Java and persistent Python communicate

Tags: java, python, package, communication

I've run into a conundrum where I'm unsure what the best method would be to having Java communicate with Python. I've looked into JPython, Jypy and Jython but I'm unsure if they could achieve what I'm looking for.

I have a Java GUI application that needs to send data to Python, and then wait for processed data to be returned back. Another caveat is that the Python application must run together with Java and remain running alongside it, it can't simply be re-run for every prompt due to the size of data that needs to be initialized in the Python script.

I thought about running the Python script on a while loop where it waits for data continuously, but I'm unsure how I would pass the data to Python from Java efficiently, and then pass it back.

The processes are going to run on a Windows system.

Comment: Can these be separate processes?  Or do you need to run both Java and Python in the same process?

Comment: They can be separate processes for sure

Comment: If you have access to the source code and can change it, I'd look at communicating over a named pipe.  Pipes are IPC (inter-process communication), that's exactly what they're for.  If you need to run the two processes on separate systems, then you need to use the network, like a REST service or something similar.

Comment: Would this work on a Windows system, and would the named pipe be able to also pass images?

Comment: It should be able to pass any data including images, and I'm sure Windows has named pipes available.